# Load Pages Using AJAX to Allow for a Continuous Music Player in Drupal

Tags: ajax, drupal

I'm looking to create a music player that will play continuously between page loads. After some research, I've decided AJAX is the best way to do this.

I'm looking to load all the site content using AJAX (minus the music player) in one container and place the music player in a separate container div at the bottom of the page.

How would this be done? Thanks is in advanced!

Comment: Divs don't persist across page loads - you're going to have to use another window or frames for that unless you want to retool your site to use AJAX page loads to load every single page.  A new window would be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

[Ajax pages](http://drupal.org/sandbox/jamix/1988012) makes it possible to load every page via Ajax with minimum effort. A player can be put in a region outside of the Ajax-loaded area, making for continuous playback. There are demo links on the project page, check them out.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked at the drupal stack Exchange site, you should be able to find some good answers there.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35893/persistent-audio-player